# Adding Events to TCollectionItem with C++ Builder 5

Tags: c++, events, tcollectionitem

My question is simple :

How to implement an event handling within a `TCollection` or `TCollectionItem` ?

When I simply add a `TNotifyEvent` to a `TCollection` Item, no compile error...

But at design time... a bad declaration error occurs...

I have tried on `TCollection` also to add a `TNotifyEvent` property... the same error occurs...

Looking at the header of the visual unit I just can't find any bad declaration (and the new event handler is correctly declared), as well as in the source code of the visual unit...

But when I tried to compile, as told before : declaration error !

Of course I have already added events properties on the `TComponent` parent object of that `TCollection`, and no error at compile time occurs...

Only if I introduce events in `TCollection` or `TCollectionItem` !!!

Any Idea ?